How to resolve hydration issue in Nextjs 15 with useOptimistic in my context utilizing React 19?
Playing with a store in Next.js 15 and using React 19 I'm running into an issue with my cart context and keep receiving a hydration error of:

An optimistic state update occurred outside a transition or action. To fix, move the update to an action, or wrap with startTransition.

in my context:
  const addCartItem = React.useCallback(
    (variant: ProductVariant, product: Product) => {
      updateOptimisticCart({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: {variant, product}})
    },
    [updateOptimisticCart],
  )

and I've been unable to find a resolution to the problem when I search and read through:

useOptimistic revert is happening after serverAction but before revalidatePath render
New feature: startTransition
Stale values returned from useOptimistic when state changes
optimistic ui updates - react
What are the rules and limitations of startTransition in React 18?
How to implement optimistic state update / push using React, Redux and Redux-Saga

dependencies:
"next": "15.0.3",
"react": "19.0.0-rc-cd22717c-20241013",
"react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-cd22717c-20241013",

The entire contents of the context file:
'use client'

import React, {createContext, use, useContext, useMemo, useOptimistic} from 'react'

import type {Cart, CartItem, Product, ProductVariant} from '@lib/shopify/types'

type UpdateType = 'plus' | 'minus' | 'delete'

type CartAction =
  | {type: 'UPDATE_ITEM'; payload: {merchandiseId: string; updateType: UpdateType}}
  | {type: 'ADD_ITEM'; payload: {variant: ProductVariant; product: Product}}

type CartContextType = {
  cart: Cart | undefined
  updateCartItem: (merchandiseId: string, updateType: UpdateType) => void
  addCartItem: (variant: ProductVariant, product: Product) => void
}

const CartContext = createContext<CartContextType | undefined>(undefined)

function calculateItemCost(quantity: number, price: string): string {
  return (Number(price) * quantity).toString()
}

function updateCartItem(item: CartItem, updateType: UpdateType): CartItem | null {
  if (updateType === 'delete') return null

  const newQuantity = updateType === 'plus' ? item.quantity + 1 : item.quantity - 1
  if (newQuantity === 0) return null

  const singleItemAmount = Number(item.cost.totalAmount.amount) / item.quantity
  const newTotalAmount = calculateItemCost(newQuantity, singleItemAmount.toString())

  return {
    ...item,
    quantity: newQuantity,
    cost: {
      ...item.cost,
      totalAmount: {
        ...item.cost.totalAmount,
        amount: newTotalAmount,
      },
    },
  }
}

function createOrUpdateCartItem(
  existingItem: CartItem | undefined,
  variant: ProductVariant,
  product: Product,
): CartItem {
  const quantity = existingItem ? existingItem.quantity + 1 : 1
  const totalAmount = calculateItemCost(quantity, variant.price.amount)

  return {
    id: existingItem?.id,
    quantity,
    cost: {
      totalAmount: {
        amount: totalAmount,
        currencyCode: variant.price.currencyCode,
      },
    },
    merchandise: {
      id: variant.id,
      title: variant.title,
      selectedOptions: variant.selectedOptions,
      product: {
        id: product.id,
        handle: product.handle,
        title: product.title,
        featuredImage: product.featuredImage,
      },
    },
  }
}

function updateCartTotals(lines: CartItem[]): Pick<Cart, 'totalQuantity' | 'cost'> {
  const totalQuantity = lines.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.quantity, 0)
  const totalAmount = lines.reduce((sum, item) => sum + Number(item.cost.totalAmount.amount), 0)
  const currencyCode = lines[0]?.cost.totalAmount.currencyCode ?? 'USD'

  return {
    totalQuantity,
    cost: {
      subtotalAmount: {amount: totalAmount.toString(), currencyCode},
      totalAmount: {amount: totalAmount.toString(), currencyCode},
      totalTaxAmount: {amount: '0', currencyCode},
    },
  }
}

function createEmptyCart(): Cart {
  return {
    id: undefined,
    checkoutUrl: '',
    totalQuantity: 0,
    lines: [],
    cost: {
      subtotalAmount: {amount: '0', currencyCode: 'USD'},
      totalAmount: {amount: '0', currencyCode: 'USD'},
      totalTaxAmount: {amount: '0', currencyCode: 'USD'},
    },
  }
}

function cartReducer(state: Cart | undefined, action: CartAction): Cart {
  const currentCart = state ?? createEmptyCart()

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_ITEM': {
      const {merchandiseId, updateType} = action.payload
      const updatedLines = currentCart.lines
        .map(item =>
          item.merchandise.id === merchandiseId ? updateCartItem(item, updateType) : item,
        )
        .filter(Boolean) as CartItem[]

      if (updatedLines.length === 0) {
        return {
          ...currentCart,
          lines: [],
          totalQuantity: 0,
          cost: {
            ...currentCart.cost,
            totalAmount: {...currentCart.cost.totalAmount, amount: '0'},
          },
        }
      }

      return {...currentCart, ...updateCartTotals(updatedLines), lines: updatedLines}
    }
    case 'ADD_ITEM': {
      const {variant, product} = action.payload
      const existingItem = currentCart.lines.find(item => item.merchandise.id === variant.id)
      const updatedItem = createOrUpdateCartItem(existingItem, variant, product)

      const updatedLines = existingItem
        ? currentCart.lines.map(item => (item.merchandise.id === variant.id ? updatedItem : item))
        : [...currentCart.lines, updatedItem]

      return {...currentCart, ...updateCartTotals(updatedLines), lines: updatedLines}
    }
    default:
      return currentCart
  }
}

export function CartProvider({
  children,
  cartPromise,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
  cartPromise: Promise<Cart | undefined>
}>) {
  const initialCart = use(cartPromise)
  const [optimisticCart, updateOptimisticCart] = useOptimistic(initialCart, cartReducer)

  const handleUpdateCartItem = React.useCallback(
    (merchandiseId: string, updateType: UpdateType) => {
      updateOptimisticCart({type: 'UPDATE_ITEM', payload: {merchandiseId, updateType}})
    },
    [updateOptimisticCart],
  )

  const addCartItem = React.useCallback(
    (variant: ProductVariant, product: Product) => {
      updateOptimisticCart({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: {variant, product}})
    },
    [updateOptimisticCart],
  )

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      cart: optimisticCart,
      updateCartItem: handleUpdateCartItem,
      addCartItem,
    }),
    [addCartItem, handleUpdateCartItem, optimisticCart],
  )

  return <CartContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
}

export function useCart() {
  const context = useContext(CartContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useCart must be used within a CartProvider')
  }
  return context
}

This context is a piggyback off of Vercel's Commerce cart-context.
In React 19 with Next.js 15 how can I resolve my hydration error around my addCartItem?
